# Internet Explorer 8 builds 18702 and 8702IC?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I'm having an issue with a strange version of IE8 which I have not come across until now.  The version causing all the trouble with me is 8.0.6001.8702IC?  Has anyone come across this version yet?

This funky version is breaking a lot of the websites I worked on, mostly asp.net 1.1 and 2.0 web sites. However, the [supposedly] final build of IE 8.0.6001.18702 is displaying my webpages perfectly.

Can anyone illuminate some light on this issue beyond "refactor your HTML and CSS"?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Where exactly have you got this IC build from and what do you mean exactly by "breaking a lot of websites"?

Answer (score 2):

The "IC" means it's an "Internet Content Provider" version - it's been customized by a 3rd party, usually with their branding.

There shouldn't be any functional differences - maybe there's a plugin that's causing the problem you're having?

Comment: In our case, there was an offensive add-on, finding out which one will take a little longer.